# How to access the IME text in a WinForms TextBox?

Tags: winforms, ime

I need to get the IME text while the user is editing it, i.e. before they hit [Enter] and thus add the "finalized" version of the text to the WinForms (.net 3.5) TextBox.

How do I accomplish this?

Some event along the lines of Java's [InputMethodListener.inputMethodTextChanged](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/InputMethodListener.html#inputMethodTextChanged%28java.awt.event.InputMethodEvent%29) would be great.

Comment: I think in Win32, so there might be a simpler way in .NET, but you could try inheriting from `TextBox` and listening for [`WM_IME_CHAR` messages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374132.aspx).

Comment: @CodyGray If you make it an answer, I'll accept. There does not seem to be any easier way.